# Configure Apache Wicket in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wicket

I have my spring application that provides REST API through `@RestController` annotation  and it works very well.
Now I want to integrate some View at my project and I want to use Apache Wicket, but I'm having problems. I created the `WebApplication` class:

```
public class WicketApp extends WebApplication {

 @Override
 protected void init() {
    super.init();
    super.getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
 }

 @Override
 public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
    return Index.class;
 }
}
```

and the Index.java and Index.html files in the same folder.

But it doesn't work and I have a 404 error. This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapp.AppConfig</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>TestApplication</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.web.wicket.WicketApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TestApplication</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my configuration file I added this method:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan({ "com.myapp.*" })
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
    public class AppConfig {

      //other configurations        

        @Bean
        public WicketApp application() {
            return new WicketApp();
        }
```

I really don't know where the problem is...

Spring version is 4.1.4
Apache Wicket version is 7.1.0
I'm using Maven.

Comment: What url gives 404? Your config looks good. @Mihir's answer is also valid but not mandatory. Do you see in your logs a message the Wicket has started in DEVELOPMENT mode ?

Comment: /myapp/app/Index.html

I can see the message

Comment: There is nothing configured to listen at "index.html". You need to use `#mountPage("index.html", getHomePage())`.

Comment: IT WORKS! But why I have to manually mount every page? In the documentation and in the examples this is not indicate...

Comment: I've added a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket uses "/" as mount point for the home page. If you want to listen additionally on "/index.html" then you have to explicitly mount it with `mountPage("index.html", getHomePage())`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention Spring app config in the wicket filter as below instead of WicketApp.

```
      <filter-name>WicketFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/resources/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: It doesn' work.

I added
<init-param>
        <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

Comment: Can you try with public class WicketApp extends WebApplication implements ApplicationContextAware ?

Comment: Leave I the setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) method empty?